# Firefox 82: tab bar merged into window title bar

Tags: gnome, 20.04, firefox

I've just updated to Firefox 82 on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. Immediately it's apparent that the tab bar has been merged into the window title bar. I'm all for saving screen real estate, but as far as I can tell, this change means that the context menu for windows is no longer available. In particular, `Move to workspace down` I use **a lot**.

Right-clicking on the title bar only produces the Firefox tab bar context menu, not the window context menu:

[image]

Is there a setting that controls this behaviour, or a way to get the window context menu that I haven't been able to find yet?

Comment: Try pressing `Alt`, this should show the window menu bar

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: _"In particular, Move to workspace down I use a lot."_ - Consider assigning a keyboard shortcut (Settings > Devices > Keyboard, I think?) to any actions you use a lot. That can really help speed things up :)

Comment: @stackzebra <kbd>Alt</kbd> shows the File/Edit/View menu bar only, which doesn't get you access to the window controls. Posts below show how to enable the title bar again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox uses legacy window decoration, i.e., the classical title bar, which is provided by the window manager. The title bar can be shown or hidden through the Firefox preferences dialog. If you hide it, you loose that right-click window context menu, unfortunately.

To directly have the context menu for windows available, your only option is to enable the title bar. Alternatively, you can still show it using the shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. A shortcut key to directly move a window down is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd>. However, this will not send the window away, but take you along with the window to the next workspace.

Answer (score 22):

If you go into Customize, you can enable the title bar again. It's a checkbox in the lower left corner on the Customize dialogue.

Comment: Good catch!! I was missing the title bar for a while

Answer (score 1):

Same on Ubuntu 18.04.  I found a solution:
Right click wherever up there, to get the Firefox tab bar context menu (the one with "Menu Bar", "Bookmarks Toolbar", and "Customise" in it.  Click Customise. Check "Title Bar" at the bottom of that Customise screen.  That's it, everything shifts down 1 "row" and is out of the window border.  (Note the menu bar is greyed out when in Customise.. I was alarmed when I noticed this and thought it broke when I moved it out of the window title.  Nope, it's fine, it un-disables as soon as you close the Customise tab.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Xubuntu.
A windows context menus is available by right-clicking firefoxes taskbar button on this xfce4 Desktop. Maybe not in other DEs?