# Some applications are not focused when clicked on their Title Bar

Tags: gnome, window, focus, 23.04

This problem started after upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04.

For example, open `gnome-terminal` (**Terminal**) and `usb-creator-gtk` (**Startup Disk Creator**). Partially overlap these two windows and allow the title bars of both windows to be visible (and clickable).

Click on the title bar of **Terminal**; it will be focused. Now, click  on the title bar (the topmost area saying "**Make Startup Disk**") of **Startup Disk Creator**; it will ***not*** be focused and **Terminal** will remain focused.

The only seemingly workaround is to click and drag a bit the title bar of **Startup Disk Creator** or click somewhere *inside* the window of **Startup Disk Creator**.

The same problem is present in LibreOffice applications, **Thunderbird** and **Firefox** with [title bar enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286491/firefox-82-tab-bar-merged-into-window-title-bar).

This is a rather annoying bug **not present in the previous versions of Ubuntu**.

Note that this problem is not present on all Ubuntu applications and it may be related to the version of GTK used in that application.

How to correct this wrong behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately not the only issue at the moment. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/leading-up-to-23-04-release-things-to-consider/34879.  Bullet eight is the one you describe. CSD/non-CSD related.

Comment: @JacobVlijm are these issues Ubuntu specific? I do not see such issues on a Fedora 38 (Gnome 44) system.

Comment: @vanadium indeed on gnome 44 (libmutter 12/mutter 44). Did you try with csd? We've noted this was reported on fedora as well. Cross-checked on Ubuntu with gnome-shell btw.

Comment: @JacobVlijm is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464737/some-applications-do-not-remember-window-state also related to the same issue?

Comment: There were fundamental changes in the way windows/frames are handled. I can reproduce what you say on 22.04/23.04. To be honest, IMHO Gnome/mutter 44 should never have made it into 23.04. It's a mess at this point, experimental at best.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, I made sure to have at least one csd application available; I tried with gnome terminal (configured to use the traditional title bar), Gimp and LibreOffice. With respect to window states, same observation as FedKad  for "Disks" and "Terminal", not so for Thunderbird, Firefox, Files.

Comment: Could this be related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464849/title-bar-full-screen-in-23-04

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug: [Single click on title bar does not transfer focus to target window (server side decorations in Xorg sessions)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2013216)

As you may see in the above bug report, the fix is released and you should get it when GNOME gets updated to version 44.1. On my Fedora 38 system, GNOME 44.1  was released a few days ago and I can confirm that the issue is fixed there.