# LibreOffice shows window title bar in slide-show mode on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: libreoffice, 23.04

On Ubuntu 23.04 (but not on Ubuntu 22.10) LibreOffice Impress does not properly enter slide-show mode, which should be entirely full screen.

Instead, Impress shows a window title bar that reads "Presenting: " and the name of the file.

How do I configure Ubuntu so that Impress will present properly in full-screen without this title bar?

I have tried both LibreOffice 7.5.2.2 and LibreOffice 7.4.6.2 on Ubuntu 23.04, and both versions have the same problem, but 7.4.6.2 entered full-screen presentation mode fine on 22.10. This leads me to think that the issue is Ubuntu 23.04, not Impress -- or at least how Impress is operating with 23.04.

Other applications correctly enter full-screen mode on my 23.04 system: GIMP, darktable, Firefox, etc.  All the others work fine in true full-screen mode.

Comment: It happens for me too in Ubuntu 23.04. It seems to be a new feature but let us say that it is a bug.  A workaround is to export to a pdf file and use evince to show it fullscreen.

Comment: Again likely related to significant problems with mutter in Ubuntu 23.04. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464827/some-applications-are-not-focused-when-clicked-on-their-title-bar?noredirect=1#comment2565506_1464827 and link provided by Jacob Vlijm in the comments.

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround: log into Ubuntu in a Wayland session, not X11.  This removed the title bar for me on 23.04.