# Ubuntu 23.04 Window Focus

Tags: gnome, .desktop, window

I just upgraded from 22.04 to 23.04. On 22.04 I could click on a window title and it would raise it and give focus. I'm not getting that on 23.04. I need to actually select with button 1 and move the window a bit to get raise and focus.

Am I missing some setting?

Comment: Issues like this have been reported elsewhere as well recently, e.g. users cannot focus an application clicking on a legacy title bar (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464827/some-applications-are-not-focused-when-clicked-on-their-title-bar?noredirect=1#comment2565506_1464827). It appears to be related with very late changes in upstream mutter. Ubuntu apparently patches libraries quite a bit. Quite some issues with window management/focus with Gnome 44 produce on Ubuntu, but not on Fedora.

Comment: @Nmath What do you mean? I was running 22.04 and was offered an update in the UI.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. 22.04 doesn't upgrade directly to 23.04. So how did you do that?

Comment: Yes, there is no direct upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04. What I did was do a clean install of 23.04 in a different partition and copied over my home directory. I did apt installs to add in needed aps I used in 22.04.

Comment: Are there official bug reports to track progress on these mutter issues? The no focus on title bar click is bothering me the most.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some applications are not focused when clicked on their Title Bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464827/some-applications-are-not-focused-when-clicked-on-their-title-bar)

Comment: Is there any way to track the issue, its clearly in the thread vnadium linked, but I don't see how to track it in bugzilla or elsewhere.